# Redirecting to the previous page upon a 500 error

Tags: python, django, error-handling, http-status-code-500

I am using Django for my web app and it uses a payment gateway for taking in transactions. I have used validations for checking the required fields for the gateway and it works just perfectly fine. Now I just crashed into a case when someone was trying to donate but the "key" itself was missing from the dict I was passing to the gateway. I tried making a payment myself and it again worked perfectly fine. I want to have my app redirect back to a particular page if in case it gets an unhandled exception such as this, that is, a 500 error. I want this 500 error redirect for just this particular view and not for all 500 errors.

Comment: share your views code and the error traceback you are getting.

Comment: Catch the exception, and redirect to the page. You may want to log the exception though.